# How to send the setResult(RESULT_OK, mystring) to other application in android

Tags: android

> How to send the setResult(RESULT_OK, mystring) to other application?. Example: my custom camera was called by other application and the other application wait for the result of RESULT_OK. My problem is how to send the RESULT_OK to the listening application?

Any suggestions?... Thanks if there is..

i'd try this but setResult got an error. I would like to pass the RESULT_OK to the other application which is waiting for the value of RESULT_OK

```
Intent tracks = new Intent();
tracks.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_SEND, cameraImagefolder);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, cameraImagefolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the last line be:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

??

Comment: this code can pass to the other application?...example im using My Tracks and i click the camera and i select my custom camera, is my custom camera send that result to My Tracks?

Comment: I thaught you had that already sort out. I don't know if the other application will receive your data!!!

Comment: This is my problem on how to send data to the other application specially My tracks

Comment: You need to find out how my MyTracks can receive data from other applications, that's very specific to MyTracks